# How to Disable Previous Date in Calender Extender Using any client Side Script OR Server Side Script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have two textboxes with calendarextender and One Label. The first textbox represents the starting date and the second textbox represents the end date, The Label Represents the No of Days Leave.

The problem i have is that if i select an end date i want to disable all dates Previous to the start date, using any of the Client side Scripts or Server Side Script.......
But Calculate the Start Date and End Date and store it in (Label)NO.OF Days Leave for this one i need Server Side Script only.

Example: Start Date is 11-12-2010 and End Date is 14-12-2010, the NO.of Days Leave is 4.

Can anyone please Help me...... I'm new in Asp.net........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never actually used the Ajax Calendar Extension but I read up some on it so here's a shot:

Doing the logic for limiting the dates on the server-side would probably be the easiest. But to the best of my knowledge the CalendarExtender doesn't allow server-side events. But a way around this is adding a hidden asp:button and a hidden field to your page and use the event `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` for the first CalendarExtender to store the date and fake a click on the button calling a code-behind method.

```
function dateClickEvent(sender, args)  
{    
    document.getElementById('MyHiddenField').value = sender.get_selectedDate();  
   (document.getElementById('HiddenDateBtn')).click();     
}
```

The markup for the button and field being something like this:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenField" runat="server" />    
    <asp:Button ID="HiddenDateBtn" runat="server" Text="Click" Visible="false" 
style="display:none" OnClick="HiddenDateBtn_Click" />
```

If you then use a RangeValidator and a ValidatorCalloutExtender you could set the range 
for the second date extender in code-behind.

```
//In your code-behind  
protected void HiddenDateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
     string firstDate = MyHiddenField.Value;  
     SecondDateRangeValidator.MinimumValue = firstDate;
}
```

And the .aspx code to the validator should be something like:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="SecondDateRangeValidator" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="SecondDateTextBox" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"
                Type="Date">
</asp:RangeValidator>
<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="SecondDateRangeValidator_ValidatorCalloutExtender"
                runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="SecondDateRangeValidator">
</ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

I haven't tried this code myself :) Just put it together after some googling and reading. Hopefully it helps.